# How to target Materialize CSS active carousel item?

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I am currently working on a website and ran into some trouble when it came to the Materialize CSS carousel. The carousel itself looks and functions fine but I am trying to write a jQuery command that displays the current active carousel items text. To sum it up, I have a P tag underneath each image and would like the P tag to show only when on the current carousel item and fade out when a different carousel item is clicked and then for that carousel items text to appear... so on and so forth. Bootstrap has more documentation on how to target their active item but Materialize has nothing in it's documentation about it... I feel like it would be an awesome effect but I'm kind of stumped on how to achieve it.

I made a JS Fiddle of the setup using stock images: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgrdy3dr/14/)

If anyone has any pointers on this I'd really appreciate it!

```
<div class="carousel">
  <a class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300">
    <p>Nala</p>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300">
    <p>Kinzasha</p>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300">
    <p>Simba</p>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300">
    <p>Kemba</p>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300">
    <p>Zefir</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
dist:0,
shift:0,
padding:20,
});
```

And the CSS

```
.carousel {
min-height: 480px;
}
.carousel-item {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
text-decoration: none;
}

img {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}

p {
font-size: 1em;
color: red;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt another framework to achieve this. Or else you can do the trick like increasing the height of the image and its parent div.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    dist:20,
    shift:0,
    padding:0,
    indicators:true
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sgrdy3dr/27/

Comment: So there really is no way to check for the current item? That's crazy... they need to work on their documentation.

Comment: you have to add setinterval function to check. I have created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sgrdy3dr/49/

Comment: I found Materialize CSS way to check for active item. It's onCycleTo: function(data). But now I'm wondering what the opposite of this function is. Because I got it to do what I want when I cycle to the active item, but how would I get it to go away when the item is no longer active?

Comment: I figured it out!!!!! Ahhh man, thanks so much for you help! I guess they do have a function for it but no documentation...